# nginx: CORS headers are not added for OPTIONS request

Tags: nginx, cors

Consider this minimal nginx server configuration

```
server: {
   listen 80;
   server_name myserver;

   location / {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS';
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }
        return 200 my-content;
   }
}
```

and the corresponding curl invocations

```
# this one works as expected
$ curl -v http://myserver
# ...
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS
# ...
```

and

```
# this one is missing the Access-Control-Allow-* Headers
$ curl -v -X OPTIONS http://myserver
# ...
HTTP/1.1 204 No content
Server: nginx
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Content-Type: text/plain charset=UTF-8
Content-Length 0
```

So the *OPTIONS* request is missing the *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* and *Access-Control-Allow-Methods* headers, while they are properly set for the GET request. Adding the *always* Parameter to the *add_header* directive doesn't work either.

I'm using nginx v1.11.1 on Ubuntu 16.04. Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: You have to copy all `add_header` directive into `if` block.  http://nginx.org/r/add_header _These directives are inherited from the previous level **if and only if** there are no add_header directives defined on the current level_

Comment: BTW, you've missed semicolon in `Content-Type` header

Comment: @AlexeyTen great, thank you, that solved my problem